# MongoDB Query to get unique of particular fields from a collection and insert into another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb. It has few entries currently.

sample entry:

```
//1
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b52693cbb49784bc24271a9"),
"username" : "sai",
"userid": "101",
"useralias" : "scharan",
"country" : "IND",
"createdby": "sai",
"lastmodifiedby": "charan",
"lastmodifieddate": "07/20/2018 16:59"
}
//2
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b52693cbb49784bc24271a9"),
"username" : "sai",
"userid": "102",
"useralias" : "kiran",
"country" : "IND",
"createdby": "kiran",
"lastmodifiedby": "kiran",
"lastmodifieddate": "07/21/2018 16:59"
}
```

First i want to exclude fields other than username and country.

I am running this query

```
db.userconfig.find({}, {_id: 0, username: 1, country: 1});
```

Here is the result

```
//1
{
"username" : "sai",
"country" : "IND",
}
//2
{
"username" : "sai",
"country" : "IND",
}
```

From this i want to prepare unique of both documents and insert into other collection.

```
    //1
    {
    "username" : "sai",
    "country" : "IND",
    }
    //2
    {
    "username" : "sai",
    "country" : "IND",
    }
```

Before inserting into other collection i want to add few other fields(createdby, lastmodifiedby, lastmodifieddate). This should ideally result in :

```
    {
        "username" : "sai",
        "country" : "IND",
        "createdby": "admin",
        "lastmodifiedby": "admin",
        "lastmodifieddate": "12/20/2018 12:15"
        }
```

Comment: Hello @Charan, are you using some specific programing language, or are you doing all through MongoDB Shell?

Comment: I am not using any specific program language. I am running through mongo shell.

Comment: Cool. Now what is your question? Your whole post has no question mark (`?`).

Comment: I am able to get //1
{
"username" : "sai",
"country" : "IND",
}
//2
{
"username" : "sai",
"country" : "IND",
} From this i want to prepare unique of both documents and insert into other collection.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to add other fields after the result, you cannot easily use the aggregation and $group operators, and would do better to do this yourself in javascript.

```
 objects = [
    {
    "username" : "sai",
    "country" : "IND",
    }
    //2
    {
    "username" : "sai",
    "country" : "IND",
    }
 ]
 var uniqueObjects = {};
 objects.forEach(function(o){uniqueObjects[hex_md5(JSON.stringify(o))]=o});
 for(var i in uniqueObjects)
 // Add your extra fields to each unique object and insert them into a collection using uniqueObjects[i];
 })
```

Comment: I am new to mongodb. How do i use javascript and run a query?

Comment: If you know the query without adding the fields after the result also you can tell me. I can also add fields after inserting the documents.

Comment: If you're running from the command line (mongo cli), you can use mongoscript just fine. Which is just javascript. If you want to save your scripts: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) **mongo documentation**

Comment: Important: actually the above code uses arrow functions and mongodb's cli javascript only uses functions. I will edit it to be something you can actually run in your cli